# Images in a JFrame

Tags: java, image, jframe

Can someone please give me an example code wich has a JFrame with an image and a something else in it, I just can't get the image working and I need an example that works. I tried some thing with buffered image and image icons but nothing works.

Comment: I'm sure google can supply many thousands of examples

Comment: Code requests are not encouraged and some effort on your part is going to be required in the future, maybe start with [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

Comment: I actually tried many times but nothing worked so I thought it was better to ask for an example that does work so that I can find my flaws and learn about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String args[])  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Image");

            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            try {
                frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL(YOUR_IMAGE_URL))),
                        BorderLayout.NORTH);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            frame.add(new JButton("Button"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```